# How to change the value of a rule in css by data binding value in KNOCKOUT?

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js, durandal

I have a loading bar which shows the progress of the project that how much the project has been completed, the width of the bar is statically done with css styling and width property, here is the code:

```
<div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 10%;">
```

I want to change the width, dynamically with data-bind attribute, How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If 'width' is a model property, then

```
<div class="progress-bar"
   role="progressbar"
   aria-valuemin="0"
   aria-valuemax="100"
   data-bind="
       style: { width: width + '%' },
       attr: {'aria-valuenow' : width + '%'}">
```

For more details check the [style binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/style-binding.html) article.

Note that it makes sense to change the `aria-valuenow` attribute, which requires the `'` around the value for Knockout to set correctly

Comment: data-bind="style: { width: percent + '%'} " > I replaced my code with this, and here the 'percent' field is coming from my model. Now the bar shows no width at all and is completely blank. But, I guess the syntax is right.

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle to debug?

Comment: aaah, i was doing a mistake, i didnot had to append the '%' sign with my percent property because I already appended it in the model :) it works fine now,

Comment: Note that if the style you are using has a `-` in it, for example `max-width`, you must use lower camel case instead e.g. `data-bind="style: { maxWidth : maxwidth }"`

Comment: @TSV I didnt downvoted, I dont have the rights to downvote :) I accepted your answer as it solved my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

To dynamically style using Knockout, we do not generally use the style binding any longer, in the same sense that we no longer use the style attribute any longer, either. In the Knockout documentation, take a look at the Knockout [CSS binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html).

Create a Knockout observable or Knockout computed observable on your model, and then using the CSS binding, de-reference that observable. Your observable should store or compute the CSS class that should be attached to your element, and simply return a string representing the class name.

Then go off to the side and write your CSS class or classes.

Comment: have read this before, this didnt solved my problem, have tried to follow what they have mentioned there but still cant dynamically bind the width :(

Comment: This doesn't show how to achieve the required width using the CSS binding